# Write $\mbox{Res}(g, 0) $ in terms of the $\mbox{Res}(f, z)$ where $g(z)=\frac{1}{z^{2}}f\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)$.

Tags: complex-analysis, residue-calculus, complex-integration

Let $M\subseteq \mathbb{C}$ finite set and $f:\: \mathbb{C} \setminus M \longrightarrow \mathbb{C}$ be a holomorphic function. Consider $g(z)=\frac{1}{z^{2}}f\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)$. The quiestion is: **What is the $\mbox{Res}(g, 0) $? Write $\mbox{Res}(g, 0) $ in terms of the $\mbox{Res}(f, z) $.**

**Remark:** I know that 
$$\mbox{Res}(g, 0)= \frac{1}{2\pi i}\int _{\left|z\right|=\varepsilon} \frac{f\left(\frac{1}{z}\right)}{z^{2}}dz.$$
Also I know that I can choose $\varepsilon>0$ small enough such that $g$ is holomorphic in $B_{\varepsilon}(0)\setminus \left\{0\right\}$. But from this last I don't know write $\mbox{Res}(g, 0) $ in terms of the $\mbox{Res}(f, z) $.

Comment: how would you express $\displaystyle\int_0^{2 \pi} \frac{f(e^{-i\theta} / R)}{R^2 e^{2 i \theta}} i R e^{i \theta} d\theta$ in term of $Res(f,.)$ ?

Comment: I already understood, this is possible by a change of variable and a suitable choice of $\varepsilon$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write the Laurent series $$f(z) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} a_n z^n.$$ Hence $$g(z) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^{+\infty} a_n z^{-2-n}.$$

The residue is the coefficient at the rank $\frac{1}{z}$.

Thus $\mbox{Res}(f, 0) = a_{-1} = \mbox{Res}(g,0)$.

If you want to do that with integrals, a change of variable $w = \frac{1}{z}$ will give you the same answer.